# Is there documentation for the Industry Compatible Hotkeys?

Tags: shortcut, documentation

I am using the industry compatible hotkeys. However I ran into this problem where whenever I follow a tutorial, I have to use the search bar to find the function of whatever command they did with the blender hotkeys. Now this isn't the issue in my opinion. The issue is that sometimes those commands dont appear on the search bar unless I do some finangling or do some specific thing by accident.

So I was wondering if theres a more extensive documentation of the industry standard hotkey than the one that I see in the blender website.

Comment: In blender 2.79 there was a function where it would import hotkeys default to Maya. I do not know if there is the same function for 2.8x

Answer (score 0):

I found the function for industry compatible hotkeys in Blender.

Go to the top left tab of the window and click on preferences> edit:

[image]

In the blender preferences, go to "Keymap".

Click on the "Blender" space at the top of the window for the preferences when on the keymap settings, and you will see more options:

[image]

1. "Blender"
2. "2.7X"
3. "Industry Compatible"

Select *industry compatible*. I don't know the hotkeys for Maya, but this should do the trick.

[image]

Comment: ah thank you. I went and check and I see theres a massive list in it. So far there arent many hotkeys in industry compatible yet apparently but hopefully in the future that might change. I can probably make my own hotkeys for now.

Comment: If this answer answered your question, please mark that. It will help other stack exchange users.